# VB - resetting a for loop?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

Okay, so I am trying to create a program that will encode and decode a vigenere cipher which will code your program depending on the key you use such as 2,5,3,7. I already have the code that takes the key the user inputs and separates each integer into an array (vKey) which is here:

```
  Const maxKeyLen = 25
  Dim vKey(maxKeyLen) As Integer
  Dim numKeys As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim vKee() As String = txtKey.Text.Split(CChar(","))
  numKeys = vKee.Length
  For i = 0 To numKeys - 1
      vKey(i) = Int(vKee(i))
  Next
```

What I need to somehow do is have this loop:

```
  For i = 0 To Len(plaintext) - 1
     For m = 0 To vKey.Length -1 
        shift = vKey(m)
        cipher += shiftIt(plaintext(i), shift)
      Next

  Next
```

So right now what will happen is if I input the key 2,3,4 the loop will end up shifting the first letter by 2, second letter by 3, third by 4 and then it will stop. I need it to somehow shift the fourth letter by 2 and continue shifting the rest of the file by using the key.

Thank you!

Comment: Your loop is wrong because you don't increment the plaintext of the number of chars already processed in the inner loop

Comment: `i` (or whatever variable you use to iterate through your loop) can be redefined as many times as you wish (until the point of creating an infinite loop if you want). That is: to make a loop restart from the beginning at any point, just do `i = -1` (bear in mind that it will add +1 before the next iteration will reach your code).